# Assigning and writing empty values for missing HTML tags to keep consistency between structures in Python

Tags: python, html

**HTML lines that I have are the following:**

```
<nonDerivativeTable>
    <nonDerivativeHolding> # First Holding
        <securityTitle>
            <value>Common Stock</value>
        </securityTitle>
        <ownershipNature>
            <directOrIndirectOwnership>
                <value>D</value>
                <footnoteId id="F1"/>
            </directOrIndirectOwnership>
        </ownershipNature>
    </nonDerivativeHolding>
    <nonDerivativeHolding> # Second Holding
        <securityTitle>
            <value>Common Stock</value>
        </securityTitle>
        <ownershipNature>
            <directOrIndirectOwnership>
                <footnoteId id="F2"/>
            </directOrIndirectOwnership>
            <natureOfOwnership>
                <value>By Wife</value>
            </natureOfOwnership>
        </ownershipNature>
    </nonDerivativeHolding>
    <nonDerivativeHolding> # Third Holding
        <securityTitle>
            <value>Bond</value>
            <footnoteId id="F3"/>
        </securityTitle>
        <ownershipNature>
            <directOrIndirectOwnership>
                <value>I</value>
            </directOrIndirectOwnership>
            <natureOfOwnership>
                <value>Career Shares</value>
                <footnoteId id="F4"/>
            </natureOfOwnership>
        </ownershipNature>
    </nonDerivativeHolding>
</nonDerivativeTable>
```

I see three "holding"s in a "table". In each "holding", there are three sets of tags: "securityTitle", "directOrIndirectOwnership", and "natureOfOwnership" that carry "value" or "footnote id" tags.

Since the existence of "value" and "footnote id" is inconsistent. I want to make two variables named for example `securityTitleValue` and `securityTitleFootnote` from each of three tags.

Thus, I want 6 variables in total: `securityTitleValue`, `securityTitleFootnote`, `directOrIndirectOwnershipValue`, `directOrIndirectOwnershipFootnote`, `natureOfOwnershipValue`, and `natureOfOwnershipFootnote`.

All six variables should have their values for each of "holding"s in the "table". That is if "footnote id" is missing for "securityTitle", the value of `securityTitleFootnote` should be empty.

However, because sometimes the values of the variables and even the tags are missing (for example, in the third holding, there are no "natureOfOwnership" tag.), I feel extremely difficult to keep the empty values and retain the appropriate data for each "holding".

**The code I have is:**

```py
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
writer = csv.writer(outfile, )
    doc = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')

    try:
        c = [i.securitytitle.contents for i in soup.select('nonderivativeholding')]

        h = [('value', lambda x: x.text), ('footnoteid', lambda x: x['id'])]
        results = [[i for i in b if i != '\n'] for b in c]
        r = [{a: (lambda x: '' if not x else x[0] if len(x) == 1 else x)([b(j) for j in i if j.name == a]) for a, b in h} for i in results]

        SecurityTitleValues, SecurityTitleFootnotes = zip(*[[x['value'], x['footnoteid']] for x in r])
    except:
        SecurityTitleValues = ''
        SecurityTitleFootnotes = ''
    pass

    try:
        c = [i.directorindirectownership.contents for i in soup.select('nonderivativeholding')]

        h = [('value', lambda x: x.text), ('footnoteid', lambda x: x['id'])]
        results = [[i for i in b if i != '\n'] for b in c]
        r = [{a: (lambda x: '' if not x else x[0] if len(x) == 1 else x)(
            [b(j) for j in i if j.name == a]) for a, b in h} for i in results]

        DirectOrIndirectOwnershipValues, DirectOrIndirectOwnershipFootnotes = zip(*[[x['value'], x['footnoteid']] for x in r])
    except:
        DirectOrIndirectOwnershipValues = ''
        DirectOrIndirectOwnershipFootnotes = ''
    pass

    try:
        c = [i.natureofownership.contents for i in soup.select('nonderivativeholding')]

        h = [('value', lambda x: x.text), ('footnoteid', lambda x: x['id'])]
        results = [[i for i in b if i != '\n'] for b in c]
        r = [{a: (lambda x: '' if not x else x[0] if len(x) == 1 else x)(
            [b(j) for j in i if j.name == a]) for a, b in h} for i in results]

        NatureOfOwnershipValues, NatureOfOwnershipFootnotes = zip(*[[x['value'], x['footnoteid']] for x in r])
    except:
        NatureOfOwnershipValues = ''
        NatureOfOwnershipFootnotes = ''
    pass


    for SecurityTitleValue, SecurityTitleFootnote, DirectOrIndirectOwnershipValue, DirectOrIndirectOwnershipFootnote, NatureOfOwnershipValue, NatureOfOwnershipFootnote in zip(SecurityTitleValues, SecurityTitleFootnotes, DirectOrIndirectOwnershipValues, DirectOrIndirectOwnershipFootnotes, NatureOfOwnershipValues, NatureOfOwnershipFootnotes):

        writer.writerow([SecurityTitleValue, SecurityTitleFootnote, DirectOrIndirectOwnershipValue, DirectOrIndirectOwnershipFootnote, NatureOfOwnershipValue, NatureOfOwnershipFootnote])
```

If you see my code, my code requires each pair of value variable and footnote variable to keep empty values whenever they are missing. However, it does not work in the case where I have no tags in the first place.

The result I want to achieve from the code is the following:

### [Want Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0VwA.jpg)

Please note that the above html lines are a simplifed version of one of thousands of html pages. One example would be "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1288992/0001181431-13-020593.txt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following helps, might not be that elegant tho.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 


html_doc = """
<nonDerivativeTable>
    <nonDerivativeHolding> # First Holding
        <securityTitle>
            <value>Common Stock</value>
        </securityTitle>
        <ownershipNature>
            <directOrIndirectOwnership>
                <value>D</value>
                <footnoteId id="F1"/>
            </directOrIndirectOwnership>
        </ownershipNature>
    </nonDerivativeHolding>
    <nonDerivativeHolding> # Second Holding
        <securityTitle>
            <value>Common Stock</value>
        </securityTitle>
        <ownershipNature>
            <directOrIndirectOwnership>
                <footnoteId id="F2"/>
            </directOrIndirectOwnership>
            <natureOfOwnership>
                <value>By Wife</value>
            </natureOfOwnership>
        </ownershipNature>
    </nonDerivativeHolding>
    <nonDerivativeHolding> # Third Holding
        <securityTitle>
            <value>Bond</value>
            <footnoteId id="F3"/>
        </securityTitle>
        <ownershipNature>
            <directOrIndirectOwnership>
                <value>I</value>
            </directOrIndirectOwnership>
            <natureOfOwnership>
                <value>Career Shares</value>
                <footnoteId id="F4"/>
            </natureOfOwnership>
        </ownershipNature>
    </nonDerivativeHolding>
</nonDerivativeTable>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')


def extract_value_or_footnoteid(tag, tagname):

    def getval(tag):
        return tag.select('value')[0].string if tag.select('value') else ""

    def getfoot(tag):
        return tag.select('footnoteId')[0].get('id') if tag.select('footnoteId') else ""

    newtag = tag.select(tagname)
    if newtag:
        return getval(newtag[0]), getfoot(newtag[0])
    else:
        return "", ""


for holding in soup.select("nonDerivativeHolding"):
    line = []
    for tagname in ['securityTitle', 'directOrIndirectOwnership', 'natureOfOwnership']:
        val, foot = extract_value_or_footnoteid(holding, tagname)
        line.append(val)
        line.append(foot)
    print(line)
```